# How to check if my RESTful API is connected to Firebase Realtime database

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

I need to know the connection status of the Firebase Realtime database in my API. I read the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) but I can't seem to get it to work like I need it too.

This is the example code in the documentation,

```js
var connectedRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/connected");
connectedRef.on("value", (snap) => {
  if (snap.val() === true) {
    console.log("connected");
  } else {
    console.log("not connected");
  }
});
```

This program seems to only log the connection status on **regain** of connection. I am currently hosting the API locally on my device. Here is the string of events that occurs.

```
(log) not connected
(log) connected
(I turn off my wifi and wait for a while)
(I turn it back on)
(log) not connected
(log) connected
```

I need it log `not connected` as soon as I turn off the wifi, ie,

```
(log) not connected
(log) connected
(I turn off my wifi and wait for a while)
(log) not connected
(I turn it back on)
(log) connected
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You tagged with `node.js`. Does that mean that the code you shared runs in Node.js, instead of in a browser?

Comment: yes, its running on node.js

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed above, Firebase's `connectedRef` only snaps the connection status on **regain** of connection.
You seem to use window's `navigator.onLine` Web API to listen on wi-fi connection status change.

Try this pseudo code snippet:

```js
window.addEventListener('offline', function(e) {
    console.log('offline');
    onWifiOfflineHandler();
});
window.addEventListener('online', function(e) { console.log('online'); });

...

function onWifiOfflineHandler() {
    var connectedRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/connected");
    connectedRef.on("value", (snap) => {
        if (snap.val() === true) {
            console.log("connected");
        } else {
            console.log("not connected");
        }
    });
}

onWifiOfflineHandler();

...
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer, but I am using node.js, this seems to be code for browser context js